# Tailwind classes not being applied in node application html file

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I set up a simple project with the purpose of writing HTML styled with tailwind. I followed the [tailwind installation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) guide to get it set up.

And I have built the CSS file but for some reason, the styling is not being applied.

This is a simple node application I just open the html file in my browser to check it and when I inspect the elements the classes are there they're just not being applied. What could I be missing?

For reference this is my `tailwind.config` file:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./*.{html,js}", "./exactcrane_template.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Note: I added an exact path to the file I want to apply the styling to, to see if that was the issue. The HTML file is at the root of my project for reference.

My `HTML` file has a link to the built css file `output.css`. I have double checked this is the correct path.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>ExactCrane</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/output.css" />
  </head>...
```

`input.css` contains:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

When I link to `input.css` some of the classes controlling font size and weight work, but nothing else works.

this is my `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "tailwind:css": "tailwind build -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css"
  },
```

Some of the `output.css` file that was generated after building with `npm run tailwind:css`:

```
/*
! tailwindcss v3.3.3 | MIT License | https://tailwindcss.com
*/

/*
1. Prevent padding and border from affecting element width. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/4)
2. Allow adding a border to an element by just adding a border-width. (https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/pull/116)
*/

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 1 */
  border-width: 0;
  /* 2 */
  border-style: solid;
  /* 2 */
  border-color: #e5e7eb;
  /* 2 */
}

::before,
::after {
  --tw-content: '';
}

/*
1. Use a consistent sensible line-height in all browsers.
2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS.
3. Use a more readable tab size.
4. Use the user's configured `sans` font-family by default.
5. Use the user's configured `sans` font-feature-settings by default.
6. Use the user's configured `sans` font-variation-settings by default.
*/

html {
  line-height: 1.5;
  /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  -moz-tab-size: 4;
  /* 3 */
  -o-tab-size: 4;
     tab-size: 4;
  /* 3 */
  font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  /* 4 */
  font-feature-settings: normal;
  /* 5 */
  font-variation-settings: normal;
  /* 6 */
}

/*
1. Remove the margin in all browsers.
2. Inherit line-height from `html` so users can set them as a class directly on the `html` element.
*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  /* 1 */
  line-height: inherit;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
1. Add the correct height in Firefox.
2. Correct the inheritance of border color in Firefox. (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190655)
3. Ensure horizontal rules are visible by default.
*/

hr {
  height: 0;
  /* 1 */
  color: inherit;
  /* 2 */
  border-top-width: 1px;
  /* 3 */
}

/*
Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
*/

abbr:where([title]) {
  -webkit-text-decoration: underline dotted;
          text-decoration: underline dotted;
}

/*
Remove the default font size and weight for headings.
*/

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
}...
```

I don't understand the purpose of this files contents. Is this actually acting as a regular css file where I need to style the elements in the conventional way?
The network tab is attempting to load the output.css but the status is failed.

There has to be an explanation for tailwind not working? I've tried deleting and resetting the project and still nothing. What could it be?

Comment: "I just open the html file in my browser" so you're not running a build process at all? And when you say you double checked the path to your output.css file, how did you check it? What does the network tab in dev tools tell you? If the output.css file is populated and the classes do not have an effect then you either don't have the right path or Tailwind has not ran it's build process to see what classes you're using in your markup.

Comment: No build process beyond the one I ran to build the output.css file. I didn't think of the network tab. It is attempting to load the output.css file but erroring although the error is not clear it only says failed as the status.

Comment: what tailwind class(es) did you put in the html file? i'd start with checking if those classes are defined in the `output.css` file, if they're defined, it's probably that your HTML file is not importing the `output.css` file

Comment: The `dist` directory is a subdirectory of where the `.html` file is located? Example: `project/page.html` and `project/dist/output.css`

Comment: Or maybe it's simply not compiling it. Did you run `npm run tailwind:css`? Or `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch` and leave the window open while you work? Did you clear Chrome's browser cache? (Just some sanity checks.)

Comment: Ah. After reading the other comments, it sounds like your HTML can't find the `output.css` file. Can you add `* { background:red !important; }` to your CSS file to verify? If so, it's likely that your path is wrong, or the file doesn't exist. Try changing the URL to `href="/dist/output.css"` instead of `href="dist/output.css"`.

Comment: Updating the path has the same issue, and yes I did build with `npm run tailwind:css`. But I am wondering about the comment that says I should have the classes I want to use defined in my output.css this is something that confused me when the file was created what is output.css's purpose? Do I need to define all the classes in it? Shouldn't they already be available?

Comment: when you do `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch`, tailwind will scan for tailwind classes that are defined in the HTML file and add those calsses to the `output.css` file

Comment: can you provide the link of your code in sandbox etc.?

Comment: Try using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/output.css" />`

Answer (score 1):

### Perhaps you opened the `HTML` file in the wrong way.

You need to open it with a static `web server`.

### the error way ❌

use the `fill://` protocol

[image]

### the right way ✅

use the `http://` protocol

[image]

### solution

> An easy way to use a static web server

```bash
# install
$ npm i http-server
```

```json
{
  "name": "tailwindcss-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "tailwind css",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch",
    "build": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css",
    "start": "http-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "tailwind",
    "css"
  ],
  "author": "xgqfrms",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "http-server": "^14.1.1"
  }
}
```

```bash
# run the npm script command, then open the bellow link
$ npm start
```

http://127.0.0.1:8080/src/index.html

[image]

### refs

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server